# What should we do with non-answers when the user can't comment?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, comments

In this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4188/gmail-forwarding-address-verification-code-for-apex-email-service) a new user came in late and added a "did you ever figure this out?" [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/12426/594).  The proper thing would have been for the user to comment on the original question, but since he's new and doesn't have any rep that option isn't available.  Any suggestions for what to do in this case?

Comment: Excellent question Ralph! That is indeed one of the limitations of this site. Its often difficult to work with a new user since you also can't take them into a chat room either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tricky one, I've closed it since it was flagged as it's definitely detrimental to the site as a source of concise information, I left a comment which the user should be able to see even if others can not.

Yes this user could't comment, but it doesn't take much effort to earn the rep required. The system is presenting a road block in this case, but I think the cost of such is worth it since it teachers people about how the site works and how to use it effectively.

Comment: A "did you ever figure this out?" is just a "me too" answer/comment, and yea, they should be deleted - and not left as a comment. The proper way is to vote up the question. The other option for the new user will be to earn the rep (in a legit way :-)  ) and than add a bounty on the question. That way it can get the needed atraction

Comment: Since SE doesn't allow you to message users, leaving "did you ever figure this out?" (esp for questions that are quite old) seems to me the only way to get the attention of the OP. Voting up a question that is months old doesn't do that. I've done this in a couple rare situations on SO with good results. Is this really never OK?

Comment: @Saariko, getting the rep doesn't get the immediate response if the new user is here in search of the answer to a specific problem they're having. IMO, "earn the rep" and you can "post your follow-up comment" doesn't convey to them that this is a "friendly community site". Agreed @jkraybill, would be nice at times to message another user. Perhaps posting a question to them with an `@` while in the chat room would be the way to do that?

Comment: @crmprogdev I think you're right about it giving the wrong impression about the community, but we can't change it, and if the restriction was removed I think the amount of extra spam and cruft would be considerable.

Comment: Note that, as a moderator, you *can* convert these to comments (attaching them to a question *or* answer) if you find they have some value. In this case, directing the author to post a separate question would've been more appropriate however.

Comment: @MattLacey so i guess the latest feeling on this is flag the moderator to convert it to a comment?

Comment: Reckon so. I typically do that most of the time, can't remember what I was thinking at the time in this instance. One issue I do sometimes have though is not knowing which other post the converted comment should be attached to!